# Can I calculate probability using line integral?

Tags: probability, density-function

Say I have two continues variables $X$ and $Y$ with joint PDF $f(x, y)$, to calculate the probability $P(X=Y)$, I have to take double integral over the "line area", that is $0$.

Can I think $P(X=Y)$ as the sum of all $f(x, y)$ where $(x, y)$ subject to $x=y$, then use line integral to sum all $f(x, y)$ up: $\int_L f(x,y) \, \mathrm{d}\sigma$ where $L$ is $x=y$. The answer is obviously wrong, so my question is, why I can't think like this?

I guess it is something related with the differential element $\mathrm{d}\sigma \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y \in \mathbb{R}^2$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line $L:x=y$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ has Lebesgue measure zero, so as long as $x,y$ are continuous variables, $P(X=Y)$ is always zero.
$$P(X=Y)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_y^y f(x,y)\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}0\cdot \mathrm{d}y=0$$
Or we have
$$P(X=Y)=\int_L f(x,y) \, (0\cdot\mathrm{d}\sigma)=0$$

Comment: So, for $n$ variables $X_1, \cdots, X_n$, the probabilities have to be calculated on the $\mathbb{R}^n$ space, and to calculate on lower dimensions requires the aid of the Lebesgue measure. Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: You have $n$ variables then you'll have to calculate the probability in an $n$-dimensional space, and a lower-dimensional space has measure 0 in a higher-dimensional space. You can transform calculations in higher-dimensional spaces to that in lower-dimensional ones, it requires the Lebesgue integral (or in simpler situations Riemann integral would suffice) of course.